# Is it possible to reuse the same UITextField using inheritance concept in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

This question might sound silly but it means a lot to me.

I have two classes - firstViewController & secondViewController . 
I have a an UITextfield in `firstViewController`.  Now i want to have UITextfield in my `secondViewController` class too.
I don't want to create new UITextfield in `secondViewController` class and i like to reuse the UITextfield created in `firstViewController` via Inheritance.

But `secondViewController` class already inheriting `UIViewController` class. So how can i achieve this (Reusing the same UITextfield for my second class)

Thanks for the time. (:

Comment: So the inheritance would be `SecondViewController` > `FirstViewController` > `UIViewController`.  What is so complicated about that?

Comment: That makes sense... OMG..! That's too simple